# Is it correct to use ACL even if there are no roles (only resources)?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, acl

I'm building a system in Zend 2 and need a way to check if an action on resource A is allowed based on different conditions of other resources (statuses or other attributes)

Since there are no actual users on the system, only resources, it seems odd to use ACL. Is there a more preferred way to do this or is this the best option?

Answer (score 1):

[According to Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list):

> *An access control list (ACL), with respect to a computer file system, is a list of permissions attached to an object.*

And if you read further:

> *An ACL specifies which users **or system processes** are granted access to objects, as well as what operations are allowed on given objects.*

So ACL seems fine to me.

Maybe you are confused with [RBAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) (Role Based Access Control). If you would use such solution, then I would say you are maybe on the wrong track.

Comment: It might be that I got confused because Zend documentation call it a "role" anyway: "a role is an object that may request access to a Resource".

Comment: sure, sorry: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.permissions.acl.intro.html

Comment: You should maybe consider building your own simple `AclService` based on the [ZF2 `AclInterface`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-permissions-acl/blob/master/src/AclInterface.php#L50) and simply always use `null` for the `$role` paramater and only use the second parameter `$resource` to find out whether the action is allowed.